# Клиент не может подключиться к WCF-сервису

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть сервис с параметрами `ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)`, `SessionMode = SessionMode.Required`. Сервис хранит ID клиентов и их каналы обратной связи:

```
private uint freeID = 0;
private Dictionary<uint, IClientCallback> clients = new Dictionary<uint, IClientCallback>();
private IClientCallback clientChannel { get => OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>(); }
```

Поле `freeID` используется для присваивания ID новым клиентам, `clientChannel` необходим для получения их каналов обратной связи.

Сервис имеет метод входа, уведомляющий уже подключившихся клиентов о приходе нового:

```
public uint EnterService()
    {
        uint id;

        lock (clients)
        {
            id = freeID++;
            clients[id] = clientChannel;

            Parallel.ForEach(clients, (channel) =>
            {
                if (clients[id] != channel.Value)
                    channel.Value.AddListenerForUser(id);
            });
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Client entered");

        return id;
    }
```

И метод, с помощью которого новоподключившийся клиент получает ID уже подключенных клиентов:

```
public uint[] GetUserList()
        {
            lock (clients)
                return clients.Keys.ToArray();
        }
```

При входе на стороне клиента используется сначала `EnterService()` для получения и сохранения собственного ID, затем `GetUserList()` для получения ID других клиентов.

После подключения клиенты через сервис могут обмениваться текстовыми сообщениями, используя этот метод:

```
public void Broadcasting(string message)
        {
            lock (clients)
                Parallel.ForEach(clients, (channel) => channel.Value.ReceiveBroadcasting(message));
        }
```

Проблема в том, что когда на клиентской стороне я запускаю бесконечный цикл отправки текстовых сообщений:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                    client.Broadcasting(textBox1.Text);
            });
        }
```

то другие клиенты в это время не могут подключиться к серверу. Пытающийся подключиться клиент спустя минуту выбрасывает исключение при использовании метода `EnterService` или `GetUserList`:

`System.TimeoutException: "Во время операции запроса в http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFTestService/Service1/ ответ не был получен в течение настроенного времени ожидания (00:00:59.9924990). Время, назначенное для выполнения этой операции, может быть составной частью более длинного тайм-аута.  Это может быть связано с тем, что служба продолжает обработать операцию, или с тем, что службе не удалось отправить ответное сообщение. Увеличьте значение тайм-аута операции (путем привода канал/прокси в IContextChannel и изменения свойства OperationTimeout), а также убедитесь, что служба способна подключиться к клиенту."`

Клиент, спамивший сообщениями, выбрасывает это:

`System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: "Последовательность прервана удаленной стороной. Продолжение надежного сеанса невозможно, так как он прерван пользователем. Сбой надежного сеанса."`

При этом если все клиенты сначала подключились, а уже лишь потом начали спамить, то их коммуникации ничто не мешает, хотя новые клиенты подключиться не могут. Что можно сделать, чтобы все работало правильно?

Comment: Паузу пробовали делать между сообщениями или нравится ДОСить канал, забивая сообщениями?

Comment: Пауза - это, конечно, очевидное решение, но мне интересно, есть ли другой, более изящный способ. Тем более, что так его действительно можно задосить и хотелось бы такого как-то избежать

Answer (score 0):

Из-за того что вы по коду раскидали локи (`lock (clients)`) - ваш многопоточный сервер на самом деле стал однопоточным. Отсюда и проблемы.

Для начала, вам необходимо вынести из-под локов длительные блокирующие операции. Проще всего это сделать вот так:

```
IClientCallback[] local_clients;
lock(clients) local_clients = clients.Values.ToArray();

// Дальше работаем с local_clients
```

Comment: Вы список массиву тут присваиваете. Так какой метод используется быстрее - `ToArray()` или `ToList()`?

Comment: @zergon321 упс. У них примерно одинаковое время.